# Find a node before and after by given element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

For Example

```
<p>Content test</p>
<div class="comment">Test content</div>
<p>lorem ispsum</p>
<p class="comment">lorem ispsum</p>

<div>
   <h4>lorem ipsum<h4>
   <p>Take action</p>
   <p>lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</p>
</div>
<h3 class="comment">Hello world</h3>
```

I have a node `<p>Take action</p>`.

Find a next element has a class name `comment` from node `<p>Take action</p>` and prev element has a class name `comment` from node `<p>Take action</p>`.

Comment: target the element using class `$('.comment')` since you want both anyway

Comment: @guradio i need to find next and prev element which had a class name `comment`

Comment: @guradio how can i get this as a node in javascript

Comment: What event are you running the code under to get the reference to the `p` element?

Comment: You can get that node using $( "p:contains('Take action')");

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i get the node `<p>lorem ispsum</p>` using third party editor. I need to find next node has class name `comment`
`

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the p tag is as follows:

```
<p id='mid'>Take action</p>
```

Using jquery (previous)

```
$('#mid').parent().prev('.comment');
```

Using jquery (next)

```
$('#mid').parent().next('.comment');
```

Comment: `next()` and `prev()` won't work from the `p`, as the `.comment` elements are not its siblings

Comment: What if i find the parent and use next() and prev()?

Comment: i think parent('div')

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is fix like mentioned in question then you can get the next element like following.

```
$( "p:contains('Take action')").parents('div').next(".comment");
```

and previous element like following

```
$( "p:contains('Take action')").parents('div').prev(".comment");
```

and if you need an first next element from any element then you can use nextAll like following..

```
$( "p:contains('Take action')").nextAll(".comment:first");
```

But for this element you are finding must be an sibling to it.

Comment: i gave the code as example. it's not exact code. and i need the output as element